# Application migration from ATG9.4 to ATG11.1

Tags: atg

Can anyone please help as i have to migrate the application running in `ATG9.4` to `ATG11.1`. I have don't have idea like how to do migration in `ATG`.

**what should be the approach and how to go about it?**

Answer (score 2):

It will be a 5 step migration, each migration step will require you to migrate to a higher version.

All of which is available in the [Migration Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55509_01/index.html) on the Oracle Commerce website.